# Combining legends made by scale_shape_manual with a named vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to use colour and shape aesthetics in a ggplot to both represent the same variable.
I am using `scale_shape_manual` because I don't like the default shapes.
To make sure I assign the desired shape to each value, I am giving `values` a named vector.
The plot is fine, but I have two legends, one for colour, one for shape.
I presume this is because shape has a named vector but colour has an unnamed vector.

I want there to be a single combined colour/shape legend, as there would have been had I used an unnamed vector. Any suggestions?

I could use `scale_colour_manual` with a named vector, but want to use something like `scale_colour_brewer`. Using `labs` to give colour and species the same name does not help (they already have the same name).

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")

ggplot(penguins, 
       aes(x = body_mass_g, y = bill_length_mm, colour = species, shape = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(Adelie = 17, Gentoo = 16, Chinstrap = 6))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Which ggplot2 version are you using? Because I got the desired outcome with your code

Comment: I get the same resuls on v3.3.5. It seems like unexpected behaviour to me.

Comment: I was in 3.3.3, after updating to 3.3.5 the legends are separated

Comment: I'm on ggplot2 version 3.3.5 in R 4.1.1

Comment: It seems to be because of the order you are providing the shape values differ from the order it is presented for the colour legend. Try with `scale_shape_manual(values = c(Adelie = 17, Chinstrap = 6, Gentoo = 16))`.

Comment: well noticed Phil. Your order (the order of `levels(penguins$species)` works as expected. Seems like a small bug to me.

Comment: @user20650 Could be, yes. Perhaps worth filing an issue and see if ggplot2 maintainers agree.

Comment: Have you decided which answer is satisfactory for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could add  `scale_color_manual(values = c(Adelie = "red", Gentoo = "green", Chinstrap = "blue"))` to override the existing color:

The advantage is: you can individually define the colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")

ggplot(penguins, 
       aes(x = body_mass_g, y = bill_length_mm, colour = species, shape = species)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(Adelie = 17, Gentoo = 16, Chinstrap = 6)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(Adelie = "red", Gentoo = "green", Chinstrap = "blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you expect such an effect?

```
library(ggplot2)
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")


ggplot(penguins, 
       aes(x = body_mass_g, y = bill_length_mm, colour = species, shape = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 6, 16))
```

[image]